# Is the first value for COLUMN_ID in SQLLite "_id" is 1 or 0

Tags: android, sqlite

I just need to know if the default first value for COLUMN_ID is one or zero?

Comment: why not test it and see for yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

default first value for COLUMN_ID is zero.